# Retirar data de EditText e somar cinco anos

Tags: java, android, data

Gostaria de fazer uma captação de uma data com um `EditText`, e a partir dela criar uma outra data somando mais 5 anos.  Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: O seu texto está confuso, mas acho que você quer pegar o texto de um `EditText`, converter ele em uma data e somar 5 anos a isso. Entendi corretamente?

Comment: Olá amigo, é exatamente isso! Obrigado!

Comment: Neste caso, a minha resposta abaixo deve te servir, né?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) e [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
EditText seuEdit = ...;
String texto = seuEdit.getText().toString();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse(texto);
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.setTime(d);
gc.add(Calendar.YEAR, 5);
String daquiHaCincoAnos = sdf.format(gc.getTime());
```

Usando [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) e [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
EditText seuEdit = ...;
String texto = seuEdit.getText().toString();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
LocalDate ld1 = LocalDate.parse(texto, fmt);
LocalDate ld2 = ld1.plusYears(5);
String daquiHaCincoAnos = ld2.format(fmt);
```

Comment: Olá amigo, muito obrigado! funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: É possível utilizar essas ferramentas utilizando somente o mês e o Ano?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");

Comment: @FelipeSzulcsewski Nesse caso, você iria querer construir uma data sem dia, o que não funciona. Você precisa apenas do mês e do ano?